Question about Existence Proof for Chinese Remainder Theorem Using Mapping
I'm confused about a proof of existence for the Chinese Remainder Theorem:
If the $n_i$ are pairwise coprime, and if $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ are any integers, then the system
$$
\begin{align}
x &\equiv a_1 \pmod{n_1} \\
  &\vdots \\
x &\equiv a_k \pmod{n_k}
\end{align}
$$
has a solution, and any two solutions, say $x_1$ and $x_2$, are congruent modulo $N$, that is, $x_1 \equiv x_2 \pmod{N}$.
I found the following existence proof on Wikipedia, but I'm confused as to how it shows the existence of a solution, $x$:
The map
$$x \bmod N \mapsto (x \bmod n_1, \ldots, x \bmod n_k)$$
maps congruence classes modulo $N$ to sequences of congruence classes modulo $n_i$. The proof of uniqueness shows that this map is injective. As the domain and the codomain of this map have the same number of elements, the map is also surjective, which proves the existence of the solution.
How does the existence of this map prove the existence of a solution to the system above? I've seen variations of the proof in several books, but it seems to be taken for granted that the bijection proves the existence, so I think I may be missing something about bijections
I found the following which gives an explanation, but I'm not sure I understand it:
Given the mapping above ($\rho$), to prove the theorem it suffices to prove that $\rho$ is a bijection. To see this, first notice that $x$ solves the system [above] if and only if $x + n_i\mathbb{Z} = a_i + n_i\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$ and that this happens if and only if $$\rho(x + \mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}) = (a_1 + \mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}, a_2 + \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}, \ldots, a_r + \mathbb{Z}/n_r\mathbb{Z})$$ If $\rho$ is a bijection, then there exists a unique $a + \mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ so that $$\rho(a + \mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}) = (a_1 + \mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}, a_2 + \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}, \ldots, a_r + \mathbb{Z}/n_r\mathbb{Z})$$
Specifically, how does this follow:
$x + n_i\mathbb{Z} = a_i + n_i\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$ if and only if $\rho(x + \mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}) = (a_1 + \mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}, a_2 + \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}, \ldots, a_r + \mathbb{Z}/n_r\mathbb{Z})$?

"How does the existence of this map prove the existence of a solution to the system above?"  The map IS the solution.  $X \pmod N$ is DEFINED to be $(x_1,x_2,....,x_k)$ if and only if $X\equiv x_i \pmod n_i$.  And that's what a "solution" means.   There's nothing more to "get".  If $f(x) = a_1,a_2, .... a_k$ then $x$ is a solution (for that $a_1,a_2...a_k$. The hard part is proving there exist such an $x$ (and that's what proving surjectivity is)

Because we define the map by $$\rho(x+N\mathbb{Z})=(x+n_1\mathbb{Z},...,x+n_r \mathbb{Z}),$$ so the equality $$\rho(x+N\mathbb{Z})=(a_1+n_1\mathbb{Z},...,a_r+n_r \mathbb{Z})$$ is the same as $$(x+n_1\mathbb{Z},...,x+n_r \mathbb{Z})=(a_1+n_1\mathbb{Z},...,a_r+n_r \mathbb{Z}).$$


$x \bmod N \mapsto (x \bmod n_1, \ldots, x \bmod n_k)$

The definition assures that $f(x) = b_1, ...... , b_k$ if and only if $b_1\equiv x \pmod n_1; b_2\equiv x \pmod n_2; ... b_k \equiv x \pmod n_k$ if and only if $x\equiv b_i\pmod n_i$ if and only if $x$ is a solution to $b_i\mod n_i$.
Say for example $N = 30;n_1=2;n_2=3;n_3=5$ and $x = 19$ so $f(19) = (19\mod 2, 19 \mod 3, 19\mod 5 )= (1,1,4)$ then it is obvious that $19$ is a solution to $x\equiv 1\pmod 2; 1\pmod 3;4\pmod 5$ because we started with the answer and made the problem with it.
What isn't so easy if we want to find an $x$ so that $f(x) = (x\pmod 2, x\pmod 3, x\pmod 5) = (0, 1,3)$, say.  But if we can find an $x$ so that $f(x)=(x\pmod 2, x\pmod 3, x\pmod 5) =(0,1,3)$ then that has to be a solution to $x\equiv 0 \pmod 2, 1\pmod 3, 3\pmod 5$ because that is precisely what $f(x)$ was defined to be.
And that's what the proof is all about.  A solution exists for each $(a_i)$ if and only if for each $(a_i)$ there is an $x$ so that $f(x) = (a_i)$ if and only if $f$ is surjective. And the solution is unique if and only if for each $(a_i)$ there is one and only such $x$, i.e. the function is injective.

$f(x) = (a_1, a_2,... ,a_k)$ so that $x\equiv a_i\pmod n_i$.  That's exactly how $f$ is defined!


This does not answer your question, but if you don't care how big the numbers get (in comparison to Bezout coefficient method, which has smaller involved numbers), there is a formula for $x \mod M$ if $x = a_i \mod M_i$, whenever thee moduli are pairwise coprime.
It's simply:
$$
x = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{M}{M_i} \right)^{\varphi(M_i)} a_i \in \Bbb{Z}
$$
You can check it simply, knowing about FLT (Fermat's little theorem).
Though the numbers grow quickly large with exponent, when you modulo any $M_i$, they equal either $0$ or $1$ right?  Because of FLT.
I use this formula a lot, because it doesn't require referring to an algorithm result (Extended GCD / Bezout coefficients) that may have a very complicated formula, and actually it probably has some kind of continued-fraction formula, if I am fresh on this topic.  Hence the simple FLT-approach.
See this recent post of mine for an interesting idea behind this formula.  It relates even to homology theory which is considered advanced math.
